# Trying to prevent duplicate values to be added to an array.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an issue with my project when it comes to adding a duplicate value to an array on a click event.

when I push the clicked item's value to the array `openedCards.push(card);` the code allows for multiple item values to be added to the array thus creating a matched value with a single item.

I have tried wrapping this code like so `if ($.inArray(card, openedCards) < 0)openedCards.push(card);` i see that the match class is no longer being added to matching pairs, or any values for that matter.

here is the [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/logikevcover/8auxLwtm/3/)

Answer (score 52):

With vanilla javascript you can do this like the following:

```
if (array.indexOf(value) === -1) array.push(value);
```

Where `array` is your array of `value`'s that you don't want duplicates of.

---

Or, you can use the following es6 syntax:

```
if (array.includes(value) === false) array.push(value);
```

Comment: hmm yea it works with preventing duplicates but for some reason this is now preventing the following code from adding the .match class I have even when two cards actually match. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are running into issues with using object reference vs value

While obj and obj2 have same value for underlying properties, they both return different values to $.inArray

```
arr = [];
obj = {}; obj.A = 2;
arr.push(obj);
obj2 = {}; obj2.A = 2;
console.log($.inArray(obj, arr)); // 0
console.log($.inArray(obj2, arr)); // -1
```

In this case, I would recommend using some other property of card to check for availability within the array

```
function containsCard(card, list) {​
   return list.some(function(elem) {
        return elem.A === card.A
   })
}

arr = [];
obj = {}; obj.A = 2;
arr.push(obj);
obj2 = {}; obj2.A = 2;
console.log(containsCard(obj, arr)); // true
console.log(containsCard(obj2, arr)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `$.inArray()`, like:

```
if(!$.inArray(value, array))array.push(value);
```