# adding unique item into array using apps script from google sheet column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, unique-key

I have a Google sheet with multiple columns such as state name, city name, outlet names. My custom apps script function takes state name, city name, and then suppose to return unique outlet names.But I get duplicate outlet names.

Function for returning state and city are working as expected. I suppose the same logic would work which worked for city and state and they are returning unique state and city. But the difference for the outlet is that it has two filters - state and city. The white state has no filter, the city has one filter that is the state.

This is my code for returning outlet names. This is a recent adjustment from the [following link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c13o2.png).

```
function getOutletLatLong(state,city){
   state ='Uttar Pradesh' //remove after test
  city ='Etawah206242' //remove after test
  var ss= getSS();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base"); 
  var getRangeLastRow =   sheet.getLastRow();;
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getRangeLastRow; i++)
  {
      let valueArr = [sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(), sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue(),sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue()];
      if(sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === state) {
         if(sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue() === city) {
           if(return_array.includes(valueArr) === false){
             return_array.push(valueArr);
           }
      }
      }
  }

  Logger.log(return_array);
  return return_array;  
}
```

My previous logic was (same used in the function returning state & city )is in the following :

```
function getOutletLatLong(state,city){
   state ='Uttar Pradesh' //remove after test
  city ='Etawah206242' //remove after test
  var ss= getSS();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base"); 
  var getRangeLastRow =   sheet.getLastRow();;
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getRangeLastRow; i++)
  {
      let valueArr = [sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(), sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue(),sheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue()];
      if(sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue() === state) {
         if(sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue() === city) {
           if(return_array.indexOf(valueArr) === -1){
             return_array.push(valueArr);
           }
      }
      }
  }

  Logger.log(return_array);
  return return_array;  
}
```

Note the difference `return_array.indexOf(valueArr) === -1` between two version. both are not working for the function 'getOutletLatLong'.

The outlet column in the google sheets has the following data. Note the duplicate. I don't want to return a duplicate. but somehow it is not happening.

```
Kuldeep mobile
Kuldeep mobile
Annu mobile
Payal Mobile
```

State and city are set fixed for testing.

I will be thankful if someone points any good solution to fix this.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c13o2.png): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700862/trying-to-prevent-duplicate-values-to-be-added-to-an-array/46700870#:~:text=if%20(array.,don't%20want%20duplicates%20of.

Here is a sample google sheet data:

| Outlet Name | India State Name | Name | VBA Number | Shopper age limit | Service Number | City | Outlet Complete Address | Outlet Latitude | Outlet Longitude | Out Pin Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kuldeep mobile | Uttar Pradesh | Ashif khan |  | 5 years | 600+ | Etawah206242 | Baluganj Usarahar road Bharthana Etawah | 26.75565 | 79.223484 | 206242 |
| Kuldeep mobile | Uttar Pradesh | Ashif khan |  | 5 years | 600+ | Etawah206242 | Baluganj Usarahar road Bharthana Etawah | 26.75565 | 79.223484 | 206242 |
| Annu mobile | Uttar Pradesh | Aman Babu |  | 5 years | 600+ | Etawah206242 | Nevilganj Bharthana Etawah | 26.750477 | 79.22093 | 206242 |
| Annu mobile | Uttar Pradesh | Lakshya Gupta |  | 5 years | 600+ | Etawah206242 | Nevilganj Bharthana Etawah | 26.747622 | 79.219063 | 206242 |

Another comparison I have tried is the following code. But sadly result still has duplicates.

```js
if (r[1] == state && r[6] == city & !vA.includes(vA)) {
      rA.push(vA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found an alternative by doing trial and error with the code. Here is what I did. I compared the array value of two indexes. But I don't know how this is working now. The lines I edited seem it will add duplicates into an array but surprisingly it has removed all the duplicates. Any clue why is that?

```js
 if (r[1] == state && r[6] == city & rA[i-1]==rA[i]) {
      rA.push(vA);
      Logger.log(rA[i]+":"+rA[i-1]);
    }
```